# How do I disable Firefox's "Hello" video-chat feautre?

Tags: firefox

A recent update of Firefox added [video-chat/IM feature](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/hello/), the last thing I want in a browser. How do I completely disable it? (Not merely remove the option from toolbar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Type `about:config` in address bar.
2. Search for "loop"
3. Set `loop.enabled` to `false`